# What is the vector space spanned by the set of the linearly independent solutions of a linear ODE called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

For all linear ordinary differential equations (ODEs), one can always find a set of all linearly independent solutions that form a complete set in the sense that any arbitrary solution is writable as a linear combination of them. What is the vector space that they span?

Comment: What do you mean by "the set of all linearly independent solutions"? There is no one set of linearly independent solutions. For example, $y'' - y = 0$ has complete linearly independent solution sets $\{e^x, e^{-x}\}$ and $\{\cosh(x), \sinh(x)\}$, as well as incomplete linearly independent solution sets like $\{e^x - e^{-x}\}$.

Comment: Perhaps my wording was not correct. I have changed it.